# Does using unordered lists instead of tables make a lot of difference?

Tags: asp.net, html, css, user-interface

A **DNN** module consisted of a few forms in which text fields, labels and date pickers were arranged using *'tr'* and *'td'* html tags. Later on, I was told to convert these tables into unordered lists, *'ul'* and *'li'* Will doing so improve the UI rendering experience drastically?

I've read the following document carefully but still have doubts: [Tables vs. Unordered Lists](http://css-discuss.incutio.com/wiki/Tables_Vs_Lists).

Comment: There are advantages to both methods, and the question is prone to start a debate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me as if you are laying out a form ('text fields, labels and date pickers'), in which case you might be better using DIV, P, SPAN and LABEL tags to organize your controls, not TABLE tags *or* Lists.

As Oded says, it's not going to impact UI rendering much, but Tables are best kept for tabular data, and I would add that Lists, ordered or unordered, are best kept for, well, data in a list :)

If you are laying out form controls, I think this discussion may be more relevant to your decision: http://css-discuss.incutio.com/wiki/Tables_Vs_Divs

At the risk of *really* starting a debate, my preferred layout for a line in an Asp.Net form is something like this:

```
<p class="form-line"> <!-- You could as well use a <div> -->
    <label>Field Name:</label>
    <asp:YOUR_CONTROL_HERE/>
    <asp:YOUR_VALIDATION_CONTROL_HERE/>
</p>
```

Comment: Ah, that article was very informative. I'd read this before also; and, ordered or unordered are best kept for data in a list. That's what I thought first.

Answer (score 2):

Doing so has nothing to do with the UI rendering experience, as far the users are concerned.

The idea is to separate the markup from presentation. You markup the form and use CSS to present it.

Tables should be left for tabular data.

Note: Browsers did hav performance issues with very large and highly nested tables, which was the only way to layout anything before CSS existed. However, since CSS does exist, it should be used for presentation instead of HTML tables.

Answer (score 2):

> 1. Tables are useful when presenting data with two dimensions of information.
> 2. Unordered Lists are useful when presenting data with a single dimension of information.

---

Above are the points worth consider in the article

and keep in mind, browser have issue with nested data, here in case of tables. so list will definitely improve performance

Answer (score 0):

@JcFx - This has not been the case actually!

```
<div style="width: 100%; margin-top: 10px">
        <div style="float: left; display: inline-block; width: 50%" class="div1">
            <div style="float: left; display: inline-block; width: 25%" class="div2">
                <ul>
                    <li class="list1">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblPrefix" runat="server" Text='Prefix'></asp:Label>
                    </li>
```

and so on.

Comment: Now you've confused me. (Easily done). What isn't the case? It's not a form?

Comment: It is a form, of course. The text boxes and date pickers are inside other DIV.

Actually, I wanted it to look just like a table hence, unordered lists.

Comment: So you're using your DIVs to make columns, and then laying items out in each DIV using a list? That seems backwards, compared to laying out rows of label / text box / datepicker. To line things up in rows, using the example I gave above, you would give the label and Asp.net control a fixed width, then float them to the left. This way you get nice rows no matter how long your label is. It's a more common layout, I think.

Comment: Exactly, I've been using DIVs to make columns. Actually, I have been forbidden to use float: left for now. I'll be using them once the final DNN skin is decided. Here in DNN we don't apply CSS to modules. Rather, we apply CSS in the skin. Makes it easier to switch skins, I guess.

I didn't mean to confuse, by the way!

Comment: The problem with laying out in columns like that, is that it's very difficult to keep the items aligned. If the label for an item wraps to a second line, then the column becomes unbalanced. I wouldn't do it that way, but this is all a question of style, so in the end it's up to you.

Comment: @JcFx - While designing this form with 50 odd fields, it was a bit messy; and design should never be this messy. Anyways, things are more clearer in my mind after reading your responses. I'll try doing it the simple way now.